# What is JAVA_HOME? How does the JVM find the javac path stored in JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java

I would like to know what JAVA_HOME is.  Where do I set the path of javac.exe and java.exe.  It is in environment variables?  When I compile a Java program from command prompt, how does the JVM find `javac.exe`?

Comment: A more clear what is JAVA_HOME question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102022/what-does-the-java-home-environment-variable-do

Answer (score 70, accepted):

JVM does not find `java.exe`.  It doesn't even call it.  `java.exe` is called by the operating system (Windows in this case).

`JAVA_HOME` is just a convention, usually used by Tomcat, other Java EE app servers and build tools such as `Gradle` to find where Java lives.

The important thing from your point of view is that the Java `/bin` directory be on your `PATH` so Windows can find the `.exe` tools that ship with the JDK: `javac.exe`, `java.exe`, `jar.exe`, etc.

Comment: @Rajper I don't think JAVA_HOME helps to locate JDK. It is only for JRE

Comment: JAVA_HOME basically to the root of JRE or JDK, while path is a separate story that makes you available executable files.

Comment: It happens that if you have JAVA_HOME, the program `java` will actually respect that and forward the command to whatever JRE is defined there. So it is not only 3rd parties who respect JAVA_HOME, `java` itself does.

Check this explanation: https://clojureverse.org/t/about-clojure-command-searching-for-java-order/4410/2

Answer (score 19):

`JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` are not used by Java itself. Some third-party programs (for example Apache Tomcat) expect one of these environment variables to be set to the installation directory of the `JDK` or `JRE`. If you are not using software that requires them, you do not need to set `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`.
`PATH` is an environment variable used by the operating system (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) where it will look for native executable programs to run. You should add the `bin` subdirectory of your `JDK` installation directory to the `PATH`, so that you can use the `javac` and `java` commands and other `JDK` tools in a command prompt window. **Courtesy**: *coderanch*

Answer (score 14):

set environment variable

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24

classpath=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\lib\tools.jar

path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin
```

Answer (score 12):

The command prompt wouldn't use JAVA_HOME to find javac.exe, it would use PATH.

Answer (score 3):

JAVA_HOME is a environment variable (in Unix terminologies), or a PATH variable (in Windows terminology). A lot of well behaving Java applications (which need the JDK/JRE) to run, looks up the JAVA_HOME variable for the location where the Java compiler/interpreter may be found.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA HOME` is used for setting up the environment variable for JAVA. It means that you are providing a path for compiling a JAVA program and also running the same. So, if you do not set the JAVA HOME( PATH ) and try to run a java or any dependent program in the command prompt.

You will deal with an error as 
`javac : not recognized as internal or external command`.
Now to set this, Just open your Java jdk then open bin folder then copy the PATH of that bin folder.

Now, go to My computer right click on it----> select properties-----> select Advanced system settings----->Click on Environment Variables------>select New----->give a name in the text box Variable Name and then paste the path in Value.

That's All!!

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable which is read by some development tools like Apache Tomcat, Apache Maven, Gradle, Jenkins etc. Usually, `JAVA_HOME` is set to point to JDK instead of JRE because these development tools need to use tools like compiler, debugger, document generator etc. which are only available in JDK since JDK is a development kit. JRE is only meant for running java applications. JDK = JRE + Development tools

Consumer facing Java applications don't read `JAVA_HOME` variable and they just need to know where the JVM is located and that's why JVM location (directory) needs to be added to the `PATH` variable. This is automatically done for you when you install Java software. Whenever you try to run a Java application by either double clicking on the app or through command line, your operating system reads `PATH` variable to locate and run JVM and it doesn't look for `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Answer (score -1):

use this command /usr/libexec/java_home to check the JAVA_HOME

Comment: Old question. A better answer is to point to the Oracle [help page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) on setting JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score -2):

JAVA_HOME is an Environment Variable set to the location of the Java directory on your computer.
PATH is an internal DOS command that finds the /bin directory of the version of Java that you are using. Usually they are the same, except that the PATH entry ends with /bin

Answer (score -2):

Basically `JAVA_HOME` is use to  set path of the java . it is use in windows.  it's used for set path of the multiple software like as `java EE` , `ANT` and `Maven`.
this is the steps to solve your problem:

only for core java to set path :
path :`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin"`
 but when you are use multi built like as `ANT` , core java then you are used `JAVE_HOME` in environment .

follow the steps :

`JAVA_HOME`:`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin"` 
`ANT_HOME`:`"C:\ant\apache-ant-1.9.6"`

Path: `JAVA_HOME`, `ANT_HOME`;
it is the systematic way to set the environment variable..

Comment: JAVA_HOME should not include the 'bin' directory.