# How to add java plugin for Firefox on Linux?

Tags: java, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon

I want to add java plugin for FireFox (v10.0.12) on Linux(Centos 5.6 64bit).

I have JDK 1.7.0_12 installed, and add a symbolic link to plugin folder under /usr/lib/mozilla to the file libnpjp2.so under  (JRE)/lib/amd64/
Followd this 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html

But I still couldn't find java plugin on my Firefox Add-ons Manager.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: If he is asking here, almost certain he is a developer. Perhaps he needs it for development ? I am really fed up of such narrow-minded reactions on here...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you want the JDK or the JRE?  Anyways, I had this problem too, a few weeks ago.  I followed the instructions here and it worked:

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Java_Install

#### NOTE: Before installing Java make sure you kill Firefox.

root@bt:~# `killall -9 /opt/firefox/firefox-bin`

#### You can download java from the official website. (Download tar.gz version)

#### We first create the directory and place java there:

root@bt:~# `mkdir /opt/java`

root@bt:~# `mv -f jre1.7.0_05/ /opt/java/`

#### Final changes.

root@bt:~# `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java 1`

root@bt:~# `update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java`

root@bt:~# `export JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jre1.7.0_05"`

#### Adding the plugin to Firefox.

**For Java 7 (32 bit)**

root@bt:~# `ln -sf $JAVA_HOME/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so  /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`

**For Java 8 (64 bit)**

root@bt:~# `ln -sf $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so  /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`

#### Testing the plugin.

root@bt:~# `firefox http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just figured out my problem is that my link is created under /usr/lib/Mozilla/plugin, which is incorrect, because I using 64 bit centos, the folder should be /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugin

Comment: Your answer was far better than whatever Oracle provided for Linux installation.  Should the `JAVA_HOME` variable point to `/opt/java/jre1.7.0_05` instead of the actual executable?

Comment: @austin it looks like JAVA_HOME's purpose is to show 3rd party tools like Gradle or Maven where the Java build tools are located. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025295/1999239

Comment: It seems like plugins are not supported (with exception of Flash) in FF since version 52.

Answer (score 9):

you should add plug in to your local setting of firefox in your user home

```
 vladimir@shinsengumi ~/.mozilla/plugins $ pwd
 /home/vladimir/.mozilla/plugins 
 vladimir@shinsengumi ~/.mozilla/plugins $ ls -ltr
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 vladimir vladimir 60 Jan  1 23:06 libnpjp2.so -> /home/vladimir/Install/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```